# Adding Conditional Style in Report Template File (*.jrtx) of Jasper Report 5.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Added conditional style and conditional expression in report template file (*.jrtx) and called in *.jrxml.

I have tested by adding the conditional style in *.jrtx file, but it was not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperTemplate PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Template//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jaspertemplate.dtd">

<jasperTemplate>
        <style name="columnhead" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#A9A9A9"/>
        <style name="alternatestyle" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#B8860B">
            <conditionalStyle>
                <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean ($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0)]]></conditionExpression>
                <style forecolor="#A9A9A9"/>
            </conditionalStyle>
        </style>
<jasperTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the way you have your code it is always going to compare 2 == 0 try (new Integer ($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 60)) == 0

Comment: @orangegoat. Okay. Thanks. But i like to know how to add conditional style in template file (*.jrtx) and to be called inside the report file (*.jasper) using <template> tag.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that, style templates are not compiled and cannot use expressions/variables/etc.

You'll need to keep conditional styles in report templates.